# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer encodeWithCoder:]

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nstimer, nskeyedarchiver

Is there anyway that i can save an NSTimer to `UserDefaults` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` and use it later ? Below is my example code

```
  static var timerDictionary : [String:Timer]? {
    get{
        let outData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "timerDictionary") ?? Data()
        if let dict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: outData) as? [String:Timer]?{
            
            return dict
        }else{
            return [:]
        }
        
    }
    set{
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newValue ?? [:])
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "timerDictionary")
    }
}
```

However my app crashes with `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer encodeWithCoder:]`.

Comment: `(NS)Timer` does not conform to `NS(Secure)Coding`. And what is the purpose to save entire `Timer` instances? Isn't `interval` and `repeating` and maybe `userInfo` sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to continue your timer when app becomes active again, the better approach will be to save yours timer last state (countdown or tick) and create new timer instance from saved state

Comment: Have you tried the approach you are suggesting ? . do you have any sample code to prove it works?